# Like Convexity: Non-Derivative Test for Cross Partials?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, convex-analysis, partial-derivative

For univariate functions, one way to test for convexity is to take the second derivitive ($f$ is convex if $\partial^{2} f/\partial^{2} x \geq 0$).  Alternatively, one could assess convexity using the formula below. If $1\geq t \geq 0$, then a function $f$ is convex iff:

$$f(tx_1 + (1-t)x_2)\leq tf(x_1)+(1-t)f(x_2)$$

Now suppose we have a multivariate function (for example, a function with two inputs $f(x,y)$). I want to know if the cross partial $\partial^{2} f/\partial x\partial y >0$ (also a second derivative). Is there a similar way of testing for a positive cross-partial using a term such as $t$ in the formula above?

Comment: This same expression is valid if $x_1,x_2$ are intended as elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: Thanks @enzotib. So then, is meeting above condition in $\mathbb{R}^2$ proof that the cross partials of $f$ are all positive?

Comment: No, the convexity implies that the Hessian matrix is positive semidefinite

Comment: @enzotib: The question was not about how to test for convexity of $f$, but whether there is some analogous way of testing for positivity of $f_{xy}$.

Comment: @HansLundmark, my answer was "No", it is not a proof that $f_{xy}$ is positive. The rest of the sentence is an added information. By the way, positive semidefiniteness do not requires $f_{xy}\geq0$

Comment: @HansLundmark, true! The question was whether there is some analogous way of testing for positivity of $f_{xy}$. Nonetheless, I'm grateful to enzotib for his insights as I did not know them beforehand.